How to compute screen-space error for LOD selection?
I'm developing a LOD selection system and I would like to select a LOD level based on screen-space error. Could someone explain how I can accurately compute the screen-space error?

How are you creating those LOD meshes? Normally, you would select the LOD based on the size of the mesh in screen space. It's those sizes which can be computed based on screen-space error, which will probably be an output of an automatic LOD generation algorithm. Alternatively, you can just set them up manually.

I am developing an HLOD algorithm in Nanite's style. Essentially, I create a hierarchy of LOD and a DAG. During the selection phase, I select a LOD for each cluster. Based on your comment, I should compute the size of my clusters in screen space Is that correct?

I'm not sure what Nanite does. I was thinking in terms of a more traditional LOD generation process.

No need to do what Nanite does; it would be sufficient to simply implement any traditional (hierarchical) LoD system. This can be done just by eyeballing it -- at what distance does a particular LoD look good (not too coarse)? And set up your LUT (lookup table) accordingly. Yes?
